# C++ double subscript operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator[][] overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload)

I've looked on the internet but can't find a definitive answer to this question so here I am.

I know that: `operator[][]()` is not a valid operator overloading, but is their a way to overload the [][] operator (used on `vector<vector<typename>>` for example).

I need this because I'm doing a sort of wrapper class which contains a vector of vector, and I would have liked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on the return type of `operator []`. You can return a type that itself supports `operator []`.

Let's say:

```
struct Matrix
{
   vector<vector<int> > x;
   vector<int>& operator[] (int i)
   {
      return x[i];
   }
};
```

Because `x[i]` return a `vector`, you can use `[]` again because `vector` has an `operator[]`.