# C++ multidimensional array operator

Tags: c++

it is possible to overload somehow operator for multidimensional array?

Something like:

```
class A {
  ...
  int& operator[][] (const int x, const int y);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator\[\]\[\] overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, that is not possible. There are two alternatives, though:

You can have `operator[]` return an array of a smaller dimension (For a 3D array, it will return a 2D array, for a 2D array it will return a 1D array, and for a 1D array, it will return a single element). Then you can "string them together" with the syntax you want. (`arr[x][y][z]`)

Alternatively, you can overload `operator()`, because that can take multiple arguments.

Then you can use it like this, to index into a 3D array for example: `arr(x,y,z)`

But you can't overload `[][]` or `[][][]` as a single operator.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, but you can achieve the same functionality overloading `operator[]()` and having it return something that supports `operator[]()` itself.

For example:

```
class A {
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec;
public:
  std::vector<int>& operator[] (int x)
  {
      return vec[x];
  }
};
```

would allow you to write:

```
A a;
//...
int y = a[1][2];
```

because `a[1]` returns a `std::vector<int>` to which you can apply `operator[](2)`.

Comment: Only problem here (in the general case) is that there is no protection against reading off the end of an array. So, if my array is of length 4 and I do a[3][2], I'd overflow on the second operator.

Comment: @iheanyi that's actually expected, even for a `std::vector`. If you want protection, use `.at` which throws an exception.

Comment: That's why I said general case. If I had my own array that I wanted to access in this way, and I couldn't use vector (or something similar - so just a normal array), there's no built in protection with your example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to overload `operator[]` and make it return a new class which only has another `operator[]`.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's just `operator[]`. As an alternative, you can overload:

```
int &operator()(int x, int y);
```

You can use that:

```
m(4, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++23, an overloaded `operator[]` will now take 0 or more arguments which behaves exactly the same as `operator()`

```cpp
class A {
  // ...
  int& operator[](std::size_t x, std::size_t j);
  // ...
};
```

invocation:

```cpp
A a = /* ... */;

a[1, 2]; // equivalent to 'a.operator[](1, 2)'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a single operator being used twice to dereference. You can dereference `[]` operator and perform the functionality and usage by using it as `[][]` by changing the return type.

Answer (score 0):

There's no operator like that. I implemented, some times ago, a matrix trying to be close to the stl standards. 
And I used this method: first I've overloaded the operator[] to return another class that I called _C_row:

```
_C_row operator[](size_type index) { return _C_row(/*some parameters*/); } ///< This operator is overloaded to permit the use of double pointer notation.
_C_row operator[](size_type index) const { return _C_row(/*some parameters*/); } ///< This operator is overloaded to permit the use of double pointer notation.
```

And in _C_row I overloaded more than the operator[]:

```
value_type operator*() { return _r[0]; }
pointer operator->() { return _i[_idx]; }
double_pointer operator&() { return &(_i[_idx]); }
reference operator[](size_type col) { return _r[col]; }
const_reference operator[](size_type col) const { return _r[col]; }
```

I found this solution is very flexible. I hope my answer could be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned before, there is no such thing as operator[][].
However, here is an an implementation using nested classes similar to what "jalf" proposed.  For sake of simplicity, I hardcoded a 3x3 raw array.

```
    class Array2D final{
    public:
        class PartialArr final{
    private:
        friend Array2D;
        PartialArr(Array2D* ptr, int index) :original(ptr), firstIndex(index) {}
        int firstIndex;
        Array2D* original;
    public:
        int& operator[](int index) { return this->original->data[firstIndex][index];  }
    };

        PartialArr operator[](int index) { return PartialArr(this, index); }
    private:
        int data[3][3];
    };
```

This solution prevents the user of Array2D to manipulate the data directly when indexing only the first dimension of the array.

const versions of both operator[] could also be added to make the class complete.