# Overloading 2D array operator and throwing exception

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, multidimensional-array, square-bracket

I've been thinking this through and didn't come up with anything useful. I have matrix represented by 2 classes:

```
class CMatrix {
public:
    CMatrixRow * matrix;
    int height, width;
    CMatrix(const int &height, const int &width);
    CMatrix(const CMatrix &other);
    ~CMatrix();
    CMatrixRow operator [] (const int &index) const; 
    ...
}

class CMatrixRow {
public:
    int width;
    CMatrixRow(const int &width);
    CMatrixRow(const CMatrixRow &other);
    ~CMatrixRow();
    double operator [] (const int index) const;
    void operator =(const CMatrixRow &other);
private:
    double * row;
```

};

where CMatrix is a container for rows of the matrix (CMatrixRow).
I need to throw an exception when someone tries to access matrix outside it's boundaries or in other words one of the used indexes is bigger than the size of the matrix. Problem is, I need to somehow pass the first index into the method

```
double operator [] (const int index) const;
```

so it can throw exception with information about both indexes, regardless of which one of them is wrong. I also want to keep it as simple as possible. Can you think of anything?

Comment: For something completely different, your `CMatrix::operator[]` probably destroys your rows, since you return a copy of `CMatrixRow`, which will later call `~CMatrixRow` and probably delete `row`. Return a reference to your row instead. And furthermore, use `std::vector` or a similar class for your rows, that hides all memory things for you. Actually, you can use `std::vector::at` in that case for exceptions…

Comment: it's a school homework and I forbidden to use std::vector

Answer (score 1):

Your `CMatrixRow` needs to be able to find out which row it is in your container. One easy way to do that is to give `CMatrixRow`'s constructor an extra parameter that is its row index, which it can then hold on to after it is created. However, this is a form of redundancy and can lead to problems if you start moving `CMatrixRow`s around.

It is common to implement matrix access with `operator()` taking two arguments instead of having this `operator[]` with a helper class. So instead of `matrix[i][j]`, you would do `matrix(i, j)`. This makes your problem much easier and might also result in a performance increase. See ["Why shouldn't my Matrix class's interface look like an array-of-array?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-array-of-array.html) for more information.

Comment: that would be helpful, however this is my school homework and it must be done as 2D array

Comment: @MichalArtazov Well I've given you an easy way to do that

Comment: yeah but my task is to make the class and one of the basic tasks is to implement [] overload...

Comment: @MichalArtazov I described how you would do it while still using `operator[]`. Just pass the row number to `MatrixRow`s constructor.

Comment: @MichalArtazov ...and this isn't a 2D array; its overloading operators to make is *look like* a 2D array as-used in code. Its as much a 2D array as `int **` (which also isn't; its a base pointer to a sequence of pointers).

Answer (score 0):

Eventualy I managed to do it like this

```
class CMatrix {
public:
    double ** matrix;
    int height, width, throwFirstIndex;

    class Proxy {
    public:
        Proxy(double * array, const int width, const int rowIndex, bool fail = false);
        double & operator [] (const int &index) const;
    private:
        double * row;
        int width, rowIndex;
        bool fail;
    };

    CMatrix(const int &height, const int &width);
    CMatrix(const CMatrix &other);
    ~CMatrix();
    Proxy operator [] (const int &index) const;
    ...
};
```

I basicaly copied this: [Operator[][] overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload)