# How does subscripting std::array multiple times work?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, stl

How does subscripting multiple times work for `std::array` even though all `operator[]`returns is a reference, without using any proxy-objects (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload))?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    array<array<int, 3>, 4> structure;
    structure[2][2] = 2;
    cout << structure[2][2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How/why does this work?

Comment: When performing operations on references, you perform them on objects they refer to.

Comment: The example you link to shows how to use a proxy object so that you can subscript an object multiple times when you have a single object that _models_ a multidimensional array. With `array<array<T, N>, M>` you literally have an array of arrays, so subscripting the outer object returns a reference to an array, which you can then subscript. No proxy needed, because this case is much simpler!

Comment: When you have a pointer `int*p`, you can compute `p+6+2`. Same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply call `structure.operator[](2).operator[](2)`, where the first `operator[]` returns a reference to the third array in `structure` to which the second `operator[]` is applied.

Note that a reference to an object can be used exactly like the object itself.

Answer (score 6):

As you say, `structure[2]` gives a reference to an element of the outer array. Being a reference, it can be treated exactly as if it were an object of the same type.

That element is itself an array (`array<int,3>`), to which a further `[]` can be applied. That gives a reference to an element of the inner array, of type `int`.