# two dimensional array overload

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have implemented a structure for containing configuration data using the stl::map back end. I have implemented the [] operator as:

```
string& config:operator[] ( const string theKey )
{
    ParamMapIter iter;

    iter = _configMap.find ( theKey );

    if ( iter == _configMap.end() )
    {
        _configMap[theKey] = "";     // Create a new blank key/value when missing key
    }

    return _configMap[theKey];
}
```

so I can do things like

```
Conf["key"] = "value";
```

Now I'd like to make this semi-two dimensional to match old style Windows config files with separate sections. e.g. so I can write

```
Conf["section"] ["key"] = "value";
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this efficiently?

I guess the real question is how to implement the double subscript. The underlying implementation would take care of the actual detail - though suggestions on that also appreciated.

Comment: `( const string& theKey )` would be a good start.

Comment: Then your first `operator []` will have to return a reference to something that implements `operator []`. Also, `std::map`'s `operator []` will automatically insert a value-initialized element if the key isn't found. No need to do manual initialization.

Comment: Your whole function could be replaced by `return _configMap[theKey]`. That already creates an empty entry if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator\[\]\[\] overload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload)

Comment: perhaps you want `std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> >` ? Then you just use it like `Conf["key1"]["key2"] = "bar";`

Comment: Does it have to match both `Conf["key1"]["key2"] = "bar";` and `Conf["key1"] = "foo";`?

Answer (score 1):

**std::map** gives you the "create if not existing" functionality in **operator[]**

See [std::map::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/)

> **If k does not match the key of any element** in the container, **the function inserts a new element** with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed **using its default constructor**).

Or C++ standard [**23.4.4.3 map element access**]

> **T& operator[](const key_type& x);**
>
> > 1 Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts
> >     value_type(x, T()) into the map.
> >
> > 2 Requires: key_type shall be CopyInsertable and mapped_type shall be
> >     DefaultInsertable into
> >     *this.
> >
> > 3 Returns: A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to x in *this.
> >
> > 4 Complexity: logarithmic.
>
> **T& operator[](key_type&& x);**
>
> > 5 Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts
> >     value_type(std::move(x), T()) into
> >     the map.
> >
> > 6 Requires: mapped_type shall be DefaultInsertable into *this.
> >
> > 7 Returns: A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to x in *this.
> >
> > 8 Complexity: logarithmic.

So if you was adding only the operator[] functionality you can simply do

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> config;
// or in C++11 style
// using config = std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>;

config Conf; 
std::map<std::string, std::string>& section = Conf["Section"];
// or again in C++11
// auto &section = Conf["Section"];
section["key"] = "value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to match both `Conf["key1"]["key2"] = "bar";` and `Conf["key1"] = "foo";`?

Then you will have to define a Section that is just like your current Config, except as below.

Change the Config [] to return a &Section.

Make an overload operator= taking a Key (ie. a std::string) this makes it possible to implement `Conf["key1"] = "foo";` in the operator=

```
_sectionMap[""] = value;
```

and adding operator std::string to return `_sectionMap[""]`

This makes the Section key "" the same as the value `Config[key1]`.