# C++: multidimensional array of my own type

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I'm writing a simple program which is basically a template for a 3D array of any data type. It is required that later on in the main function the element of the array can be accessed directly (i.e. a[1][2][3] = 3; can be used without warnings). Here is what I have so far:

```
template <class T>
class CArray3D {
public:
    T*** tempArray;
CArray3D(int x,int y,int z){
    tempArray = new T**[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
        tempArray[i] = new T*[y];
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++) {
            (tempArray)[i][j] = new T[z];
        }
    }
};
T& operator[](const int x,const int y,const int z);

};


template <class T>
T& CArray3D<T>::operator[] (const int x,const int y,const int z) {
    return tempArray[x];
}
```

But now I get this error: overloaded operator[] must be a binary operator (has 4 parameters). I tried changing it to

```
operator[][][](const int x, const...)
```

but then I get the error: operator[] cannot be the name of a variable or data member. So I'm not sure how to do it now.
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

The main function is given (yeah it's a homework):

```
int main() {
CArray3D<int> a(3,4,5);
int No = 0;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
            a[i][j][k] = No++;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
            cout << a[i][j][k] << ",";

return 0;
}
```

So I have to use a[i][j][k] here.

Comment: Read about "proxy classes". Also, use a 1D array for storage, as this guarantees contiguous memory and hence it will be faster than using pointers to pointers. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload

Comment: Please take a look at the linked question in my previous comment, it explains how to do it for a 2D array. You can then extend it to 3D.

Answer (score 0):

The "proxy class" mentioned in the comment is the most standard method.

However since this is only your homework, and if you
just want to use it in `main()`, then you can just return a `T**`.

```
T** operator[](const int x) {
    return tempArray[x];
}
```