# n-dimensional Matrix operator[]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let's assume i want to implement a class for n-dimensional Matrix of values of type T:

```
template <typename T> class Matrix
{
 Matrix(const unsigned &dimensions ); //constructor
 T &operator[](int idx);  //set data operator
 const T &operator[](int idx) const; //get data operator
}

Matrix m(3);
m[0][0][0] = 1;
m[1][2][3] = 4;
```

How can I write an operator[][] to access data inside n-dimensional Matrix. 
Eg:

Is there a difference between writing operator of for 2-dimenstional Matrix, 3 etc?

**EDIT 1**

This question is similar to "[Operator[][] overload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6969881/4077900%20Operator[][]%20overload)", but it's about more general case, about n-dimesional Matrixes.

Although the below answer is correct:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11109487/4732868

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6969881/4077900 ?

Comment: In reference to the linked question and answer above, your proxy object might need to contain special information such as which dimension is being accessed.  Actually, the proxy could be another `Matrix` with a special constructor.  This is fairly easy if you implement your matrix storage as a single block of memory. Then you can just flag it as an intermediate object, set the dimensions accordingly, and perform any other matrix operation on it - effectively it becomes a slice.  Might not be appropriate for other operations that perform strided slices, but that's not really what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
// Matrix.h
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <map>

/**
 * This is the default container class using in Matrix. This can easily
 * be changed through template paramenters of Matrix. See below for more
 * about what the container is used for.
 */
template <typename T>
class DefaultContainer : public std::map<int, T>
{

};

/**
 * Matrix is a class template that implements a multi-dimensional storage
 * of specific type T. The Container is responsible to how these Ts will
 * be stored and retrieved from memory.
 * This is the general case for dimensions > 1. For the simple case of 1
 * dimension see below.
 */
template <typename T,
          int dimensions,
          template <typename> class Container = DefaultContainer
          >
class Matrix
{
    /**
     * A Matrix of n dimensions is actually an array of matrices each has
     * n-1 dimensions.
     * This is what happens here. m_data, in its simple case, is an array
     * of itemTypes each of them is defined as a Matrix of dimensions-1
     */ 
    typedef Matrix<T,dimensions-1, Container> itemType;

    Container<itemType> m_data;

public:
    /**
     * This returns an item of the array m_data which is probably a matrix
     * of less dimensions that can be further accessed be the same operator
     * for resolving another dimension.
     */
    itemType& operator[](int idx)
    {
        return m_data[idx];
    }

    const itemType& operator[](int idx) const
    {
        return m_data[idx];
    }
};

/**
 * This is the simple case of a one-dimensional matrix which is technically
 * an array in its simplest case.
 */
template <typename T,
          template <typename> class Container
          >
class Matrix<T,1,Container>
{
    /**
     * Here we are defining an array of itemType which is defined to be T.
     * so we are actually defining an array of T.
     */
    typedef T itemType;

    Container<itemType> m_data;

public:
    itemType& operator[](int idx)
    {
        return m_data[idx];
    }

    const itemType& operator[](int idx) const
    {
        return m_data[idx];
    }
};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

Example Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Matrix<int, 2> m;

    /**
     * m here is a two-dimensional matrix.
     * m[0] is resolving the first dimension of the matrix. it is like
     * getting the first row which should be an array of items. And this
     * is actually what m[0] returns. It returns a one-dimensional matrix
     * (an array) whose items can also be accessed using operator[] to
     * get one of those items m[0][1].
     */

    m[0][1] = 1;
    m[1][2] = 5;

    std::cout << m[0][1];
    std::cout << m[1][2];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KishanKumar I added more description three days ago. I hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this in a very round-about way: I made the Matrix a vector of vectors (for 2-d) and overloaded the `operator[]` to return a vector, and since the vector object has an overload for `operator[]` it gives the illusion that you're doing what is essentially done in the array (`array[int][int]`).  It would be hard to specify dimensions this way, however.  Another option is to just do what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload) (link courtesy of momo) and use the `operator()(int, int, int, etc...)`.

Comment: Vector of vectors is a pretty gnarly way to implement a matrix, as it scatters your data all over the heap.  Every extra dimension you add makes it worse!  It might be appropriate in some cases to have a vector at the outer dimension and partition the data into sensible blocks with good cache locality.