# overload [ ] [ ] operator for image manipulating

Tags: c++, image-processing

i've got a Class Image with a member called buffer, a vector of unsigned char that store the pixels of image. I'd like to handle this buffer as a matrix.i'd like to access to the buffer as **img[ i ][ j ]** but i've not idea how? anyone can suggest me a solution?

here's my tentative:

```
unsigned char * &Image::operator[](int i) {

       return buffer[ rows+i  ]
}
```

i read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload) then i think that is possible. my class is like that:

```
class Image {


private:

unsigned char * buffer;
int buf_size;
int rows;
int cols;
Phisical_img_manager phisical_img_manager;

const char * in_img_filename;


public:

unsigned char * & operator[](int i);

Image(const char * in_img_filename);

unsigned char * get_buffer();
int get_cols();
int get_rows();

};
```

Comment: Have `operator[]` return a row or column object that itself implements `operator[]`.

Comment: with a nested class?

Comment: @userfi Before overloading `[]`, [see this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie beautiful!! thus you suggest me to use  `(i,j) ` operator right?

Comment: @userfi - I leave it to you to read the linked FAQ and decide.  Looks like your app is better suited for overloading `()`, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Your opeartor[] returns type uchar*, so you should be able to use Image[i][j] as is...did you try?

Comment: On second thought looks like your 2D is already typed as 1D statically (my brain thought of dynamic 2D array for some reason), in which case all you're missing is the reference (see 101010's answer)...but if this compiles maybe not...clarify if this question needs a different answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution

You could do it in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) as below:

```
class Image {
  int rows, cols;
  unsigned char *buffer;
public:
  // ...  
  unsigned char*       operator[](int const i)       { return &(buffer[i * cols]); }
  unsigned char const* operator[](int const i) const { return &(buffer[i * cols]); }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a11e202352968d84)

### Discussion

Your buffer is a contiguous block of memory. Of size `N = rows * cols`.

[image]

However the notion of an image is a set of pixels arranged in a 2D construct/matrix:

[image]

What we want is to arrange this 2D construct in the 1D buffer in computer's memory. We can do this in two ways:

1. Row major order.
2. Column major order.

**In *row major order* we store each row of the image one after the other**. That is, for the following size `2x2` image

[image]

the respective buffer storage would look like:

[image]

**In *column major order* we store each column of the image one after the other**. That is, the buffer storage for the same size `2x2` image would look like:
[image]

Programming languages that support multi-dimensional arrays either implement row-major or column-major storage order for them. In C and C++ row-major order is used.

In the code showed above we implement row-major order. We define an overloaded subscript operator that takes as input the row index (e.g., `i`) we want to access. Multiplying this `i` with the number of columns we get the starting index of the `ith` row in the image. We return the address of the element that lies in this specific address. This address marks the beginning of a sub-array of the original buffer as well as the beginning of the `ith` row. To clarify further see the following code example:

```
Image I(2, 3);
I[1][2] = 42;
```

calling `I[1][2] = 42` is like calling:

```
(I.operator[](1))[2];
```

sub-call `I.operator[](1)` returns a pointer to the address where the second row of the image starts. Then we use this returned pointer as an ordinary dynamic allocated array. In this specific example we add 2 to this pointer (i.e., that is what `[2]` does) and thus we get the element of the row that lies 2 positions after the first element of the row (i.e., the third element of the second row of the image).

### Alternative Solution For C++11

If your compiler supports C++11 and smart pointers you could do the following scheme in order to avoid memory management. Furthermore I would overload `operator()(std::size_t const, std::size_t const)` because overloading as above you expose the buffer and thus you're hurting encapsulation:

```
class Image {
  int rows, cols;
  std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> buffer;
public:
  Image(int const rows_ = 0, int const cols_ = 0) 
  : rows(rows_), cols(cols_), buffer(new unsigned char[rows * cols]) {}
  Image(Image const &other)
  : rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols), buffer(new unsigned char[rows * cols]) {
    std::copy(other.buffer.get(), other.buffer.get() + (rows * cols), buffer.get());
  }
  Image(Image &&other) 
  : rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols), buffer(std::move(other.buffer)) {
    other.rows = 0;
    other.cols = 0;
  }
  unsigned char&       operator()(std::size_t const i, std::size_t const j) {
    return buffer[cols * i + j];
  }
  unsigned char const& operator()(std::size_t const i, std::size_t const j) const {
    return buffer[cols * i + j];
  }
  Image& operator=(Image const &other) {
    rows = other.rows;
    cols = other.cols;
    buffer.reset(new unsigned char[rows * cols]);
    std::copy(other.buffer.get(), other.buffer.get() + (rows * cols), buffer.get());
    return *this;
  }
  Image& operator=(Image &&other) {
    rows = other.rows;
    cols = other.cols;
    buffer.swap(other.buffer);
    other.rows = 0;
    other.cols = 0;
    return *this;
  }
  // ...
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/603bd35a1f4b3314)

Comment: could you explain better your method pls? thanks a lot

Comment: @userfi What would you like me to clarify further, doesn't the code speaks for itself?

Comment: @userfi The answer overloads `operator()`, just as the FAQ I linked to in the comment section above explains.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand the code in the first solution, i usually have access to element ** i,j ** of the buffer using `buffer[ i*rows + j ]  can you explain how it does? the second solution it'ok. thank's a lot! :)

Comment: @userfi fair enough give some time and I'll explain.

Comment: @101010 thank's a lot,  i'll wait your explanation  :)