# Operator [] overloading updating 2 values c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Does anyone know if it's possible to overload the [] operator and update two values with the input.

Example given:

I have the following function in my class now:

```
    void add(T1 input1, T2 input2)
    {
        // both variables are std::map
        normal_map[input1] = input2;
        reversed_map[input2] = input1;
    }
```

But I would like to have it that the [] operator updates both values, example:

```
    class["input1"] = input2; // should do the same as the above add function
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sure, you could make your own class that would do this.

Comment: @NathanOliver I already have a class, the function specified is a function in the class, that's why I named the variable "class"

Comment: Okay, then you just need to provide an [overloaded operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for it.

Comment: Also, you can't have a variable named class as class is a keyword.

Comment: @NathanOliver I also already have an overloaded operator, my question is how to update 2 values, I am able to update 1, but not 2. Also the class variable was meant as example, it's not my actual code

Comment: Handy reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator\[\]\[\] overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload)

Answer (score 1):

The subscript operator is only meant to give access via a single returned reference ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)):

```
R& T::operator[](S b)
```

Because of that, you won't be able to access those two maps at once without creating a sort of proxy class, which would make access via the subscript operator very counterintuitive.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep the add method then. Not sure why everybody keeps downvoting my question, as far as I can see it wasn't asked yet

Comment: @Pimmmo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload

Comment: @Pimmmo See this for a proxy class example (not that I recommend doing this): https://godbolt.org/z/-VybGu

Comment: @Pimmmo As far as the downvotes are concerned, I don't see your question as an exact duplicate of the linked question, even though it has the same answer. Because of this, I don't see any reason to downvote.