# Why can´t I overload the C++ operator[] with two parameters?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know that this works:

```
struct vtx
{
    long  operator[](long line)
    {
        return line;
    }
};
```

but why can´t I instead do something like this to emulate a two column access? Is there any way to do it?

```
struct vtx
{
    long  operator[](long line, long column)
    {
        return line + column; //resolved later
    }
};
```

Comment: Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload)

Comment: Just use `long operator()(size_t line, size_t column);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`operator[]` is defined to only accept 1 parameter. It is not possible to accept 2 parameters, but you can accept a tuple instead:

```
struct vtx
{
    long  operator[](std::tuple<long, long> loc)
    {
        return std::get<0>(loc) + std::get<1>(loc);
    }
};

// used as foo[std::make_tuple(0, 1)]
```

Comment: You'd probably use `foo[{0, 1}]` instead. But then you might as well use `operator()` in the first place, which can actually take multiple arguments like `foo(1, 2)`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Wow, I didn't know curly braces for tuples worked. Thanks!