# How to overload multiple subscript of array index operator?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Let's say I have a class, let it be `foo`. It contains object `someclass obj[10][10]`.

Now I want to refer to `bar`, which is an object of type `foo`, in such a way that `bar[7]` is equivalent to `bar.obj[7]` and returns an object of type `someclass*`. It's rather simple.

But I also want to refer to `bar` in such a way that `bar[7][3]` is equivalent to `bar.obj[7][3]` and returns an object of type `someclass`. It's not that simple right now...

How to do it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Operator\[\]\[\] overload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6969881/10871073)

Comment: If you want the first one to return a pointer, the second dimension is already done.

Comment: it can be done, but the much simpler is to use `operator()(size_t,size_t)` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in such a way that bar[7] is equivalent to bar.obj[7] and returns an object of type someclass*.

But if it returns `someclass*`, then it wouldn't be equivalent to `bar.obj[7]`. It would need to return `someclass(&)[10]` in order to be equivalent.

Note that you may want to have a const overload as well.

> But I also want to refer to bar in such a way that bar[7][3]

As long as you overload the subscript operator as described, you can do this - it works both with your pointer suggestion, and my reference suggestion.