# Returning type of operator[] in 2d array template class using std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword, stdvector

I have my class Table below. Pay attention at the way I have implemented operator[]. The reason i have used decltype(auto) as a return type is because (to my knowledge at least) when you would apply your operator twice in row  (eg. my_table[i][j] ), the returned types are different: after first application it would be a vector& after the second consecutive application it would be T. It works fine and well but to my surprise if I just rewrite operator[] as follows it still works fine:

> ```
> vector<T>& operator[](size_t input) const{
>     return data[input];
> }
> ```

The question is WHY? how does it return the required reference to the requested element in t[i][j]?

Original code:

```
template <typename T>
class Table{
public:
    Table(size_t r_num, size_t c_num) : data(r_num , vector<T> (c_num, T{})) {}

    decltype(auto) operator[](size_t input) const{
        return data[input];
    }
    decltype(auto) operator[](size_t input){
        return data[input];
    }
    void Resize(size_t r_num, size_t c_num){
        data.resize(r_num);
        for(auto& it : data)
            it.resize(c_num);
    }
    pair<size_t,size_t> Size() const{
        if(data.empty() || data[0].empty())
            return pair{0, 0};
        return pair{data.size(), data[0].size()};
    }
private:
    vector<vector<T>> data;

};
```

Comment: Second `[]` applies to `std::vector<T>`, not to `Table`

Comment: You may want to reconsider the logical operator, here: `if(data.empty() && data[0].empty())`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok, you actually precisely answered my question. Now I feel dumb, I should of understood that myself. Thank you!

Comment: @Bob__  Yep, it is plain wrong.

Comment: @IvaniKO: Notice there exists question about [`operator[][]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah i know that it looks like i have a question about operator[][] because i formulated it that way, but in reality im interested in a more general case. For example if my template class is not a table but rather a  multidimentional array with different types e.g. 
<class T, class P, class M >
instantiating like: Milti_array<vector<T>,vector<P>,vector<M>> my_array
so now i apply a chain of [] to my_array obj. like this: my_array[][][]; first two operators would pertain to my_array class and now "decltype(auto)" would actually be necessary for the operator[] overload. Agreed?

Answer (score 1):

`my_table[i][j] = 3` is essentially the same thing as:

```
auto& tmp = my_table[i];
tmp[j] = 3;
```

Taking that into consideration, both of these are actually 100% equivalent:

```
vector<T>& operator[](size_t input) {
    return data[input];
}

// same thing as

decltype(auto) operator[](size_t input) {
    return data[input];
}
```

They both return a `std::vector<int>&`, and the second indexing operation applies to that vector.

So why do you need to use `decltype(auto)` then? It's because `auto` strips out references:

```
auto operator[](size_t input) {
    return data[input];
}

// same thing as

vector<T> operator[](size_t input) {
    return data[input];
}
```

Which returns a *copy* of the row, and would prevent assignment.

Comment: Thx for reply, ive learned about auto vs decltype(auto). My problem was that I somehow didnt realize that the second operator [] would apply to the vector<T>& and thus its already an operator that is overloaded for class "vector" not class "table".

Answer (score 0):

We have:

```
Table t;
t[i][j] = 7;
```

While the first `operator[]` applied is overloaded in class `Table`(returns: `vector<T>&`), the second `operator[]` would apply to the `vector<T>&` and thus its already an operator that is overloaded for class `vector` not class `table`.